# Django filter queryset in admin page

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-queryset, django-filter

I have three models in simple Django Project.
I want to filter Versions by brand while adding in admin page.
I've tried in different ways and one of them is iclude in attached code.
admin.py file also likes as it shown.
Any suggestions ?

````
class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Version(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} ({self.manufacturer})"




class Car(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    version = models.ForeignKey(
        Version,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to=Q(manufacturer=OuterRef('manufacturer_id'))
    )
    year = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    color = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mileage = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.brand} {self.version} {self.year} {self.color}"```


class CarAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['version'].queryset = self.instance.brand.versions.all()


class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CarAdminForm


admin.site.register(Car, CarAdmin)
````

this is how I tried but w/o success.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter something in admin panel you can use `list_filter` set it to the list or tuple contaning the fields of model you want to filter. You can also you can also span relations using `__` for example

```
@admin.register(Version)
class VersionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       list_filter = ['brand']
```